# Animate Layer Opacity with UIView.Animate

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have 2 `CALayers`, each with an image. Both have an initial `Opacity` of `0`.

I want to animate Layer1's `Opacity` to `1` over 1 second, starting straight away. Then after a delay of 0.5 seconds, I want to animate Layer2's `Opacity` to `1` over 1 second. These 2 layers sit on top of one another.

What I am trying to achieve is having the first image fade in, then while it is fading in, fade the second image over it.

But I cannot use `UIView.Animate` for some reason as it does not animate at all, just sets the values straight away.

```
        UIView.Animate(1, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, () => 
        {
            backgroundLayer.Opacity = 1;
        }, () => UIView.Animate(5, () => 
        {
            backgroundLayer2.Opacity = 1;
        }));
```

Here is simply tried to run the animation straight after one another and it still just sets the values right away and there is no animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guys are correct in that I was trying to animate layers using the incorrect methods. What I ended up doing was replacing the layers with `UIImageView` and using `UIView.Animate` to change the `Alpha` properties.

Not only was this easier to code, it seems that `UIImageView`s are actually more performant when it comes to images.

Answer (score 3):

UIView animations are intended for animating UIView properties and don't seem to play well with CALayers. Using UIImageViews instead of CALayers would solve your problem (then you should use the imageView.alpha property instead of the layer.opacity property).

However, if you insist on using CALayers you can animate them with CABasicAnimation. The code below accomplishes the animation you described (note that this is Swift code, as I don't use Xamarin).

```
    var animation1 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    // Don't go back to the initial state after the animation.
    animation1.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation1.removedOnCompletion = false

    // Set the initial and final states of the animation.
    animation1.fromValue = 0
    animation1.toValue = 1

    // Duration of the animation.
    animation1.duration = 1.0


    var animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation2.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation2.removedOnCompletion = false

    animation2.fromValue = 0
    animation2.toValue = 1

    animation2.duration = 1.0

    // Add a 0.5 second delay.
    animation2.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.5

    // Animate!
    backgroundLayer.addAnimation(animation1, forKey: "opacity")
    backgroundLayer2.addAnimation(animation2, forKey: "opacity")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only animate following properties with UIView.Animate:

- UIView.Frame
- UIView.Bounds
- UIView.Center
- UIView.Transform
- UIView.Alpha
- UIView.BackgroundColor
- UIView.ContentStretch

For more sophisticated animations you have to use CABasicAnimation like in @bjornorri answer.